# WSO2ESB Twilio connector: How to get handle paging

Tags: wso2, twilio, wso2-esb

How to handle paging with the WSO2ESB Twilio connector (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Twilio+Connector)?

For example, the connector provides getSmsList functionality (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Twilio+Connector#TwilioConnector-getSmsList) where a response includes paging information (i.e. nextpageuri attribute, that is to be used to fetch next x records). However, the documentation doesn't say how to use the connector to get the next page of results. Or is this not possible with the connector (in which case using the connector loses purpose a bit since I have to resort to plain REST calls anyway)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what connector is, but the response you receive from Twilio should be the same.

To get a list of SMS messages associated with this account, including the SID, status, and more for each message, use twilio.getSmsList and specify the following properties. The list includes paging information.

Their example:

```
<twilio.getSmsList configKey="MyTwilioConfig">  
    <to>%2B14159352345</to>  
    <from>%2B14158141829</from>  
    <dateSent>2009-07-06</dateSent>  
</twilio.getSmsList>
```

Should give you something like the Calls output [example response from the documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/response#response-formats-list-paging-information) but for your SMS List where paging information is represented with a unique URIs:

```
<TwilioResponse>
```

> ```
>     <Calls page="0" pagesize="50"
>     uri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID/Calls"
>     firstpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID/Calls?Page=0&PageSize=50"
>     previouspageuri=""
>     nextpageuri="/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID/Calls?Page=1&PageSize=50&AfterSid=CALL_SID">
>         <Call>
> ```

```
            <Sid>CALL_SID</Sid>
            <DateCreated>Fri, 13 Aug 2010 01:16:22 +0000</DateCreated>
            <DateUpdated>Fri, 13 Aug 2010 01:16:22 +0000</DateUpdated>
            <ParentCallSid/>
            <AccountSid>ACCOUNT_SID</AccountSid>
            <To>+15305431221</To>
            <From>+15104563443</From>
            <PhoneNumberSid>PHONE_NUMBER_SID</PhoneNumberSid>
            <Status>queued</Status>
            <StartTime/>
            <EndTime/>
            <Duration/>
            <Price/>
            <Flags>
                <Flag>outbound-api</Flag>
            </Flags>
            <ApiVersion>2010-04-01</ApiVersion> <ForwardedFrom/> <CallerName/>
            <Uri>/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID/Calls/CALL_SID</Uri>
            <SubresourceUris>
                <Notifications>/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID/Calls/CALL_SID/Notifications</Notifications>
                <Recordings>/2010-04-01/Accounts/ACCOUNT_SID/Calls/CALL_SID/Recordings</Recordings>
            </SubresourceUris>
        </Call>
        ...
    </Calls>
</TwilioResponse>
```